# Questions on creating an empty template class just for the purpose of subclassing

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance

I am trying to create a plugin system within my objective-c project so I can just create a class that follows certain convention and it would work right out of the box.

These classes contain common headers (which includes protocols and categories), and also needs to follow the included protocols. But other than that each class is very distinct and don't share any code.

I don't want to have to write the same lines every time I need to write a plugin so thought about creating a base class like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Helper.h"
#import "ComponentProtocol.h"
#import "UIView+Extension.h"

@interface Component : NSObject <ComponentProtocol>
+ (UIView *)someProtocolFunction;
@end
```

The class has NO implementation
And then whenever I need to create one of these classes I would just create a class that looks like this:

```
#import "Component.h"
@interface CustomComponent : Component
@end
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is this an OK thing to do? The base class won't have a single line of code in it since I'm just using it as a template. Or if there's a better way to do this?
2. As you can see in the code, the protocol requires a class method. I don't know how I would go about this in the subclasses. If it was an instance method I could just call `[super someProtocolFunction];` and then add the subclass-specific logic, but I don't know how this would work in a class method setting.